# Optimizing multithread sensor collection service on android

Tags: android, multithreading, optimization, sensors

I have the below java class for Android studio which is basically a service that I'm running. The code basically registers some sensors from android on different threads and collects their events/data on each rotation/sensor-trigger and writes on strings formatted on the influxdb line protocol. I enter all that string data in different queues for each sensor. I then at the same time create a thread pool for each queue and drain the strings compressing them into gzip format and then writting them on files. I have to keep the compressed line protocol file implementation but it seems like the cpu is reaching over 60% whenever the service is on. This should be runned for days so it wouldn't be efficient. Do you have any ideas to optimize it?

```
public class MonitorService extends Service {

    Config config;

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    private int delayPeriod ;
    NotificationManager NotiManager;
    int notificationId = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "Monitoring";


    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "2";

    FusedLocationProviderClient client;

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    private String deviceName;
    public static String userName;

    SensorChecker checker;
    Timer t;
    private static int timeWindowMinutes;
    RequestHandling requestHandling ;

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> accelQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> gyroQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> magneQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> barQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> gpsQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    private volatile boolean canceled = false;

    private final List<BaseSensor> sensors = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        
        canceled=false;

        requestHandling = new RequestHandling(MonitorService.this);

        requestLocationUpdates();
        registerSensors();
        startProcessingQueue(gpsQueue, "gps");
        scheduleRequests();
    }


    private void registerSensor(int sensorType, Class<? extends BaseSensor> sensorClass, String preferenceKey, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> sensorQueue) {
        if (checker.isSensorAvailable(sensorType)) {
            BaseSensor sensor = null;
            try {
                Constructor constructor = sensorClass.getConstructor(Context.class);
                sensor = (BaseSensor) constructor.newInstance(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (sensor != null) {
                sensor.setEnabled((boolean) SharedPreferencesHelper.get(this, preferenceKey, true));
                sensors.add(sensor);
                sensorMonitoring(sensor, sensor.getName(), sensorQueue);
                startProcessingQueue(sensorQueue, sensor.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerSensors() {
        checker = new HardwareChecker((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));

        registerSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, Accelerometer.class, "allow_accelerometer", accelQueue);
        registerSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE, Gyroscope.class, "allow_gyroscope", gyroQueue);
        registerSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE, Barometer.class, "allow_barometer", barQueue);
        registerSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD, Magnetometer.class, "allow_magnetometer", magneQueue);

        String[] sensorNames = new String[sensors.size()+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < sensors.size(); i++) {
            sensors.get(i).register();
            sensorNames[i] = sensors.get(i).getName();
        }
        sensorNames[sensors.size()] = "gps";
        //create directories for the sensor files
        new FileHandling(MonitorService.this,sensorNames,userName);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("Destroy Service");
        canceled=true;
        if(MonitoringFragment.restartServiceOnDestroy){

            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);

            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }else{
            stopTracking();
            unregisterSensors();
            t.cancel();
        }
    }

    public void stopTracking() {
        if((boolean) SharedPreferencesHelper.get(MonitorService.this,"allow_gps",false)){
            client.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);

        }
    }


    private void sensorMonitoring(BaseSensor sensor, String sensorName, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> sensorQueue){
        sensor.setListener(new BaseSensor.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onTranslation(long timestamp, float[] values) {
                int window = getCurrentWindow();
                String chunkId = FileHandling.generateChunkId(sensorName, userName, window);
                String tz = getLocalTimezoneOffset();

                String builder = sensorName + ",user=" + userName + ",device=" + deviceName + ",chunk_id=" + chunkId +
                        ",tz=" + tz +
                        sensor.interpretSensorValues(values) +
                        " " + timestamp + "\n";
                sensorQueue.add(builder);
            }
        });
    }


    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        if((boolean) SharedPreferencesHelper.get(MonitorService.this,"allow_gps",false)){
            LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 1000)
                    .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
                    .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(2000)
                    .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(100)
                    .build();

            client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

            int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,

                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

            if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Request location updates and when an update is

                mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        int window = getCurrentWindow();
                        String chunkId = FileHandling.generateChunkId("gps", userName, window);
                        String tz = getLocalTimezoneOffset();

                        String builder = "gps,user=" + userName + ",device=" + deviceName + ",chunk_id=" + chunkId +
                                ",tz=" + tz +
                                " lat=" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude() +
                                ",long=" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude() +
                                ",acc=" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getAccuracy() +
                                ",alt=" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getAltitude() +
                                ",bear=" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getBearing() +
                                ",vel=" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getSpeed() + " " + locationResult.getLastLocation().getTime()  + "\n";
                        gpsQueue.add(builder);
                    }
                };

                client.requestLocationUpdates(request,mLocationCallback , null);

            } else {
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startProcessingQueue(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> dataQueue, String sensor) {
        Runnable processQueueRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!canceled) {
                    drainQueueAndWriteLog(dataQueue, sensor);
                }
            }
        };

        // Submit the task to executor
        executor.submit(processQueueRunnable);
    }


    private void drainQueueAndWriteLog(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> dataQueue,String sensor) {
        List<String> dequeuedRotations = new ArrayList<>();
        String data;
        while ((data = dataQueue.poll()) != null) {
            dequeuedRotations.add(data);
        }

        if (!dequeuedRotations.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String[] parts = dequeuedRotations.get(0).split(",");
                String chunkId = parts[3].split("=")[1];
                byte[] b = GZIPCompression.compress(dequeuedRotations.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").replaceAll(", ", ""));
                FileHandling.writeGzipFile(sensor,chunkId, b);

                FileHandling.manageDirectorySize(sensor);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    

    private String getLocalTimezoneOffset() {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        int offsetInMillis = tz.getOffset(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        int offset = offsetInMillis / 3600000;
        return String.format("%02d:00", offset);
    }

    public static int getCurrentWindow() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return hours * (60 / timeWindowMinutes) + minutes / timeWindowMinutes;
    }
}
```